# Htmlunit javascript response is not being reflected

Tags: javascript, htmlunit

I am trying to to post a comment from a webpage.. Comment web page has textarea and a button type input

here is html of textarea

```
<textarea class="aui-field-input aui-field-input-text" id="_33_wgdr_postReplyBody0" name="_33_postReplyBody0" wrap="soft" style="height: 100px; width: 500px;"></textarea>
```

and here is the way I am writing some text into textarea

```
HtmlTextArea hta = (HtmlTextArea) commentPage.getElementsByName("_33_postReplyBody0").get(0);
hta.setAttribute("value", "This Is Generated Text");
```

Button input in html page is

```
  <input class="aui-button-input" onclick="wgdr_postReply(0);" type="button" value="Reply" id="_33_wgdr_postReplyButton0"/>
```

I have tried to click on button in either this way

```
 HtmlButtonInput hbi = (HtmlButtonInput) commentPage.getByXPath("//*[@value='Reply' and @type='button']").get(0);
    HtmlPage test = hbi.click();
```

or this way

```
  HtmlButtonInput hbi = (HtmlButtonInput) commentPage.getByXPath("//*[@value='Reply' and @type='button']").get(0);
  String functName = hbi.getAttribute("onclick");
  ScriptResult scriptResult = commentPage.executeJavaScript(functName);
```

as a result my webpage and thus database should have a new comment "This Is Generated Text" which is not the case at all...
I have initialized my webclient in following way:

```
WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.INTERNET_EXPLORER_8);
webClient.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
    webClient.setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.setPrintContentOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.setTimeout(60000);
    webClient.setJavaScriptTimeout(60000);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(10000);
```

I have been digging into this since two days with no fruitful outcomes...Please post your thoughts
Thanks,
-Asrar

Comment: which version of HtmlUnit are you using ? try latest (may need to be built). Also did you tried with another BrowserVersion ?